# Как получить массивы обратно?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Из массива 0 и 1, получаю массив чисел (числа равны количеству 0 и 1).
Не могу понять, как получить обратно массивы 0 и 1?

```js
var arr = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0];
var countZero = 0;
var mode = 0;
var arr1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   if (mode === arr[i]) {
            countZero++
   }
   if(mode != arr[i]) {
       arr1.push(countZero);
       countZero = 1;
       mode = arr[i];
       } 
   }
   arr1.push(countZero);
   console.log(arr1);
```

Comment: так он же у вас остался arr

Comment: А как узнать, что в массиве `[
  4,
  3,
  4
]` означает нули, а что единицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var arr = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0];
var countZero = 0;
var mode = 0;
var arr1 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
 if (mode === arr[i]) {
  countZero++
 }
 if (mode != arr[i]) {
  arr1.push(countZero);
  countZero = 1;
  mode = arr[i];
 }
}
arr1.push(countZero);

// преобразуем в оригинальный массив

var bits = [];

for (var i = 0, currentBit = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
 for (var count = 0; count < arr1[i]; count++) {
  bits.push(currentBit);
 }
 currentBit = +!currentBit;
}

console.log(String(arr));
console.log(String(arr1));
console.log(String(bits));
```

Comment: добавь пояснения что у тебя происходит в коде.

Answer (score -1):

Вот так можно без особых костылей и лишних циклов сделать все в одну строчку.

```js
let arr = [3, 4, 3];

newArr = arr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue, index) => accumulator.concat(Array(currentValue).fill(index % 2 ? 1 : 0)), []);

console.log(newArr);
```